# Why Jsp files not mapping with the Controller return view in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-boot

i`m working on a Spring boot project. i just create this controller to return login view.

```
@Controller
public class loginController {
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }
}
```

**login.jsp** file is in **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp **

I set prefix and suffix in the application property file as like this.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

As same as i set the dependencies like this.

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My project structure is like this.

[image]

If i run the program and hit localhost:8080/login i got following White label error. can anyone suggest me why this happens and the solution

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Comment: which spring boot version you are using ?

Comment: @ShafinMahmud um using 2.0.6.RELEASE.

Comment: @RaminduNanayakkara give a screenshot of your project structure

Comment: @AvijitBarua I upload it pls check .

Comment: @RaminduNanayakkara where is your main class ?

Comment: @RaminduNanayakkara Check my answer ! I updated my asnwer

Comment: Adding dependancies ryt?

Comment: Follow my answer. Hope it will solve your problem @RaminduNanayakkara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `main` class under `com.example`!
and 
Try replacing

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

to

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And this one is also needed

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

And your project structure should be like https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaK8l.png

Comment: Please show you project structure @RaminduNanayakkara

Comment: Main class is in the com.example.demo package. my LogingController is in com.example.controller package .. so?

Comment: @RaminduNanayakkara Put `main`  class under `com.example` not in other package. Drag the main file inside `com.example` . Hope it will work

Comment: @RaminduNanayakkara You were getting error because your main class couldn't scan your controller class ! So main class should be under main package

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following maven dependency:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

Jsp needs dependency on javax.servelt to handle the request.

UPDATE:

Your jsp directory location is not handled by default. Please move it under:

> src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp

[image]

UPDATE:
 make sure that your SpringBootApplication is scanning the controller . You must see something like this in the logs:

```
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET]}"
```

Please add on your SpringBootApplication the annotation `@ComponentScan("com.example.controller")` to scan your controller or move the SpringBootApplication in the common package `com.example`

Comment: @Adina This is view resolver issue. This has nothing to do with `jstl`

Comment: @Adina.. do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @ShafinMahmud without the servlet dependency, the tomcat will not process your request and what you will see is Whitelabel Error Page with status 404 not found.

Comment: @RaminduNanayakkara could you please remove <scope>provided</scope> from tomcat-embed-jasper, reimport maven project and try again?

Comment: @Adina Still same. i dont know why this happen.

Comment: @RaminduNanayakkara I've updated my answer, the location of your jsp is not handled by default. Please add the mentioned dependency and move the jsp under the mentioned location

Comment: @Adina SO what would be the prefix in application property

Comment: @RaminduNanayakkara the same as you've mentioned. Based on your update, your Controller is not scanned at all. please move the SpringBootApplication under package `com.example`